# How to Interrupt Java Semaphore.tryAcquire Function

Tags: java, exception, synchronization, semaphore

I've a function which calls `Semaphore.tryAcquire(timeout, timeunit)` function. Now I want to interrupt this tryAcquire functions so that the caller function will throw some exception. My code idea is as below:

```
public void run() throw InterruptedException{
    semaphore.tryAcquire(timeout, timeunit);
}

public void interrupt(){
   // interrupt my run() function execution so that run() will throw InterruptedException
}
```

Any possible way to do that?

Comment: Have you considered consulting the Javadoc?

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at [this tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/interrupt.html), which covers your exact question in great detail. The basics of it: the Thread class has an [interrupt](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#interrupt--) method. Simply calling this will cause blocking operations, like `tryAcquire`, to throw an InterruptedException.

```
static void main(String[] args)
{
    Thread child = new Thread(){
        public void run()
        {
            try
            {
                Thread.sleep(4000);
                // or in your case, semaphore.tryAcquire(timeout, timeunit);
            }
            catch (InterruptedException e)
            {
                System.out.println("We've been interrupted!");
            }   
        }
    }

    child.start();
    child.interrupt();
}
```